# React Native 'unable to resolve module `moment-timezone`' despite it being in node_modules

Tags: javascript, react-native, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run a React Native project, `lucy-app`, which manages its packages through Yarn. In the `src` directory there is a `utils.js`:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ tree lucy-app/src -L 1
lucy-app/src
├── actions.js
├── api.js
├── app.js
├── components
├── containers
└── utils.js
```

Both `moment` and `moment-timezone` appear in `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.19.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
```

There is a `moment-timezone` directory in `node_modules`:

```
/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:node_modules kurtpeek$ find . -name 'moment-timezone'
./moment-timezone
```

The `utils.js` file imports `moment-timezone` as follows:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

However, when I try to run `react-native run-ios`, I get the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `moment-timezone` from `/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/src/utils.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:311:1719)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:96:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:269:4352)
    at /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:201:36
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:256:306)
    at /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:256:536
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:256:217
    at addDependency (/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:256:92)
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

Following the suggestions, I've tried `rm -rf node_modules` followed by `yarn install`, but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas what is going wrong here?